# Run two different variations of same .exe file with different .ini configurations

Tags: windows, exe

I am working with a program (abc.exe) in Windows 10 and I am wondering if it's possible for me to create two different variations (shortcuts) of the same abc.exe file each working with different .ini configurations.

```
1. config1 - at path C:/abc/config1.ini
2. config2 - at path C:/abc/config2.ini
```

So, I want to create two exe shortcuts of the same program

```
1. abc1.exe that works with config1
2. abc2.exe that works with config2
```

Is there any way to do that in Windows?

Thank you.

Comment: It depends how that program loads it’s configuration

Comment: I do have access to the source code of the code to that program

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

Allow the configuration to be specified on the command line: `myapp.exe /config=c:\whatever.ini`

Option 2:

Call `GetStartupInfo` and if the `STARTF_TITLEISLINKNAME` flag is set you can get the .lnk shortcut you were launched with in the `.lpTitle` member.